# Popcorn popcorn.js on/off button for subtitles/captions

Tags: javascript, button, html5-video, caption, popcornjs

I'm using popcorn.js to add some subtitles/captions to my video.  These automatically are shown in the video.  I'm currently creating custom video controls using html and JavaScript.  I would like a button I created to toggle the captions on and off.

Here is my html button and video (currently the onclick function "Captions" is empty)

```
 <input type="button" value="Captions" id="captions" onclick="Captions()" class="button"/>

<video id="video" width="896" height="504" data-setup="{}" >
<source src="video/MyVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<source src="video/MyVideo.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="video/MyVideo.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
<p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5. Maybe you should upgrade.</p>
</video>
```

Here is some of my JavaScript using Popcorn

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

       var popcorn = Popcorn( "#video" );true;


       popcorn.subtitle({
            start: .5,
            end: 2.5,
            text: "Subtitle Text"

       popcorn.subtitle({
            start: 2.5,
            end: 9.5,
            text: "Or captions"
       });
        }, false );
```

I'm new to JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

Update: how do I get it so the captions don't auto play.  I'd like them to be off when the video starts playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popcorn has `enable` and `disable` methods that can turn any given plugin on and off.

Because you defined your popcorn instance inside the event listener function, you'll want to set up the click handler in there as well. So, for your html...

```
<input type="button" value="Captions" id="captions" class="button"/>
```

And your script...

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var popcorn = Popcorn( "#video" );
    var showSubtitles = true;
    document.getElementById('captions').addEventListener('click', function () {
        //toggle subtitles
        showSubtitles = !showSubtitles;
        if (showSubtitles) {
            popcorn.enable('subtitle');
        } else {
            popcorn.disable('subtitle');
        }
    }, false);

    /* fill in your subtitles here... */
}, false );
```

Official documentation here: http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#disable

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so very much!! It works!! The only thing is that the captions show up automatically.  How can I set it so that they only show up when you click the button.  Thank you!!

Comment: Also how can I get it so that the button says "captions on" and captions off" in its various states.  Sorry I know this is so basic, but I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Ok I figured out the "Captions on" and Captions off" text. I added
    document.getElementById("captions").value = "captions off";
below the popcorn.enable('subtitle');  I still need help with the no auto captions though

Comment: Good job figuring out how to change the text. Disabling by default is easy. Just run `popcorn.disable('subtitle');` right after you load up the subtitle events. (You should be able to run it before too - there was a bug that prevented you from doing so, but I believe it's been fixed.)

Comment: Thank you very much!  FYI to anyone else reading this answer you put the popcorn.disable('subtitle'); after your subtitles but before the }, false);  I also had to make some adjustments and switched popcorn.enable and popcorn.disable in order for the buttons to function properly.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. If you're going to start with subtitles disabled, you want to set `showSubtitles = false` at the beginning. Or swap everything as you've done.